# Keras: How to use `image_dataset_from_directory` to load test set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to load dataset as follows,

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir, 
                                                                    labels='inferred', 
                                                                    label_mode='categorical',
                                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                                    image_size=(224, 224))


val_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(val_dir, 
                                                                  labels='inferred', 
                                                                  label_mode='categorical',
                                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                                  image_size=(224, 224))
```

However, when I check the document looks like this argument `labels` seem to be a must-have one,  but my test data has no labels, so how can I load test data? Is there a convenient and unified way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data isn't labeled, I don't think you can call it the *test set*, since you won't be able to evaluate the performance of your algorithm using it.

The argument you're looking for is `label_mode`, see the [`documentation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory). If you set it to `label_model=None`, it will not return a target;

> **label_mode**: **'int'**: means that the labels are encoded as integers (e.g. for sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss).
> **'categorical'** means that the labels are encoded as a categorical vector (e.g. for categorical_crossentropy loss).
> **'binary'** means that the labels (there can be only 2) are encoded as float32 scalars with values 0 or 1 (e.g. for binary_crossentropy).
> **None** (no labels).